# Bootstrap Dropdown won't work even script it's already imported

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I wanted to make a drop down menu on Laravel but unfortunately it won't work the `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js` but other javascript file works perfectly. Can somebody tell me which part I'm wrong?

Folder structure:

[image: SC]

header - Navigation bar

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @if (Auth::check())

            <li class = "dropdown">
                <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" role = "button"
                aria-haspopup = "true" aria-expanded = "false"> Documents<span class = "caret"></span></a>

                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href = "">Create Documents</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        @else
            <li><a href = "{{ route('auth.login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>


        @endif
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Template

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href= "{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ URL::asset('css/select2.min.css') }}">

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('src/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

with

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

as far i know jquery file have to be loaded before bootstrap js file

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap Javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) page:

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files).